# High temperature limit of ideal quantum gas

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, fermions, partition-function, chemical-potential

I am reading ideal quantum gas from Kardar's Statistical Mechanics.

[image]

$VII.35$ is the representation of pressure, number density and energy density in the form of $f_m^{\eta}$.
$z=e^{\beta\mu}$ where $\beta=\frac{1}{K_bT}$.
Later tjey try to analyze the behaviour of $f_m^\eta(z)$ for the high temperature limit.
Under this limit they are taking $z<<1$.
But $z=e^{\frac{\mu}{K_bT}}$. So the limit of $z$ as $T\to\infty$ depends on the sign of $\mu$.
If $\mu>0$, then $z\to\infty$ and if $\mu<0$, then $z\to 0$.
But the derivation does not specify about $\mu$. So how can we take $\mu$ to be negative?
**Edit**.
As suggested in the comments, the chemical potential of an ideal gas is negative. So we can carry forward this result to quantum ideal gas also.
But for fermions we know that chemical potential can be positive also.
So how can we take $z\to 0$ for high temperature limit.

Comment: If you compute $\mu$ for a classical gas, you will find that it is negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. Can you tell what exactly it means for a gas to have negative chemical potential?

Comment: Also how can we apply the result of classical ideal gas to quantum ideal gas?

Comment: Because at high enough temperature, all gases will behave like classical gas, so that tells you the right limit.

Comment: Actually, you can calculate $z=e^{\beta \mu}$ for a classical gas (but using the correct formula for the partition function that includes $1/h^{3N}$ and $1/N!$ factors), the result is $z=n\lambda^3$ where $\lambda$ is the thermal de Brogile wavelength. Being a classical gas means $n\lambda^3\ll 1$, so $z\ll 1$.

Comment: @MengCheng, I have understtod your point. So basically all quantum gas behaves like ideal gas is our assumption. Is there any way where we can prove $\beta$ to be negative for quantum gas at high temperature and then our assumption follows directly from that? Or we have to always stick to that assumption?

Comment: I don't think we should call it an assumption. Once we take the $z\rightarrow 0$ limit and find the classical ideal gas behavior, we basically prove that this is the correct limit to take. The "assumption" is more like a physical argument to figure out which limit is the right one to take.

Comment: If you want a more direct "derivation", then we look at $n\lambda^3 = f_{3/2}(z)$. High temperature/low density means $n\lambda^3\ll 1$, so we need to know how $f_{3/2}(z)$ behaves. Then we can show that $f_{3/2}(z)$ is monotonically increasing with $z$. Since $f_{3/2}(0)=0$, to have a small $f_{3/2}(z)$, $z$ also needs to be small.

Comment: Ok, now understood. So, basically we have to look at $n\lambda^3$ and this gives $z=e^{\beta\mu}<<1$ and thus $\mu$ to be negative at high temperatures.